# Laravel dompdf not accepting Tahoma font

Tags: laravel-4, dompdf

I installed Tahoma font using the `load_font.php` from ttf file it was installed successfully so now I can see the file `Tahoma.ufm &  Tahoma.ttf` inside the folder `/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/`

I also checked the file `dompdf_font_family_cache.php` and found the array installed correctly

```
'tahoma' =>
  array (
    'normal' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'Tahoma',
    'bold' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'Tahoma',
    'italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'Tahoma',
    'bold_italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'Tahoma',
  ),
```

I checked the package I am using configuration file `app/config/packages/barryvdh` I checked where fonts are stored so they were stored in `/storage/fonts` which I copied `Tahoma.ufm` to.

These are the trace steps I took but until now I can't mange to get Tahoma to work on the output file which contains Thai characters that are not showing correctly

What I am missing here?

Comment: What does your output show? Does dompdf just ignore the font and use a fallback?

Comment: When I use font-face: Tahoma; it doesn't show any Thai character and it falls back to the default font.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your html?

Comment: It shows correctly when it is displayed as html so I doubt it is html issue, but here is an example of what I have in the html that is converted to pdf. is there any tips I should know to trace this?

`<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-family: Tahoma,'open-sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 1cm 0;
  text-align: justify;
}
.free {
width:65%;
word-break:break-all;
}
</style>

<p class="free">ภาษาไทย</p>`

Comment: You said the fonts are stored in /storage/fonts with the package. Did you copy both the UFM and the TTF? I'm not sure it will make a difference if your dompdf_font_family_cache file is updating to point at `DOMPDF_FONT_DIR`, though maybe the laravel package defines that constant. Otherwise it sounds like everything is fine.